# A textarea with no wrap in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How do I create a non-wrapping textarea in Chrome using CSS?

I know this works, but it's not CSS:

```
<textarea wrap=off>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) property:

```
textarea {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not totally sure but try

```
textarea {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

// EDIT:
Felix Kling was faster than me :).